# How to always show grid 2 column with any device screen type

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a gridview, but it was always lined up two columns, I wish it was always lined up two columns.

This is grid layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newsScroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F5F5F5" >

   <GridView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/newsScrollerContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</ScrollView>
```

And this is item in grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="130dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem, when I use the device nexus runs perfectly, but if I use a smaller screen devices will be just show one coloumn, as shown below:

[image]

And if i use the tablet, so will be five coloumn.
My question is that how it's always a two-column grid when i open in device anything or any screen size.

Thanks.

Comment: auto_fit doesn't mean 2, you know.

Comment: SSSSSSSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO????? still not working change auto_fit to 2 :-), maybe i think in ImageView android:layout_width="130dip" .

Comment: so, no need to shout, thank you, and if you tried the set column number to 2 already, that would have been a good thing to mention earlier, given the all the answers that suggest this course of action. anyway, yes, 130dip width is the second more obvious thing that prevent display, as there is no room for twice that on the screen. (also, if you think this is the solution, shouldn't you try it before asking ?)

Comment: Okay, i'm sorry man, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` just use : `android:numColumns="2"`
In each grid item replace `fill_parent` with `wrap_content`.
A more complicated solution will be to calculate the screen width in code and then set the item width by code also.

Comment: That's probably because your images in each item are too wide to fit into Nexus screen. make the image width 100 or reduce the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the android:numColumns to 2, not auto_fit

```
 <GridView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newsScrollerContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
```

Comment: still not working, maybe i think in ImageView android:layout_width="130dip" .

Answer (score 0):

You can set the number of columns by using this property `android:numColumns=2` of grid view in your xml or  using this method of grid view `setNumColumns(2)`.**Dont use auto fit**.

Comment: thanks for reply piyush, but i setCumColoumns="2" still not working.

Comment: Then i think the width of the image view is the problem for you.